# nodejs difference between global and this

Tags: node.js

I do not understand the difference between this and global in node js.
It looks like to be the same thing to my eyes.

Let's have a look in the nodejs interpreter:

```
> this.toString()
'[object global]'
```

Okay so i suppose this is the same thing than global when we are in the global scope. Let's do the same thing in a function. (i have also tried a subfunction)

```
> f3= function f1() { function f2() { console.log(this.toString()); } f2(); };
[Function: f1]
> f3()
[object global]
```

As you can see here this is global too.

Can anyone tell me when this is not the same thing than global ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone tell me when this is not the same thing than global ?

In Node specifically:

- Inside a *module* `this` refers to `exports`

In JavaScript in general:

- When a function is invoked in such as way that `this` is set implicitly or explicitly:

  - Called via `.call`/`.apply` (explicit)
  - As a method (`foo.bar()`) (implicit)
  - As constructor (`new Foo()`) (implicit)
  - The called function is *strict* (`this` will be `undefined`)
- When a function's `this` was explicitly bound to another value (via `.bind`)

There are only two cases where `this` refers to the global object:

- `this` in global scope
- A *non-strict*, unbound function is called the "normal" way: `foo()`.

---

See also [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3127429/218196)